# To check code execution flow of C program in ubuntu

Tags: c

Is there any software available in UBUNTU 13.10 to check line by line code execution of C programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gdb is gnu-debugging tool that comes pre-installed in Ubuntu. It is popularly used to debug C programs.

You can install(just in case you don't have it) using `sudo apt-get install gdb`.

To use gdb, you can refer to either [the manual page of gdb](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/gdb/), or the [gnu documentation for gdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/) or [there are hundreds of tutorial available explaining gdb](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=gdb%20tutorial&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=OK9NU9OmH6rO8geU84HIAg). You may find it a bit complex in the beginning, mainly because it is a command-line tool, but you'll find it very useful once you get your hands on it and practice.